# Grouping 2D array of instances

Tags: c++, optimization, 2d-games

I have a working solution for this, though I am convinced there must be a better implementation. In a nut shell the problem is this:

I am working on a connect>=3, bejewelled style puzzle game. When the state of the 'board' changes I group all the pieces such that if they are 'connected' horizontally or vertically they share an ID. This is how I do it currently:

[pseudo]

```
for all( array object* )
{
    if !in_a_group() check_neighbours( this )
}

void check_neighbours( ID )
{
    if ( check_is_same_type( left ) )
    { 
        if !in_a_group() this.ID = ID ; check_neighbours( ID )
        else if( in_a_group ) change_IDs(this.ID, ID ) 
    }
    same for right ...
    up ...
    down ...     
}
```

That is a really dirty pseudo version of what I do. 
I recursively call check_neighbours, passing the ID of the first branch piece forward (I use this pointer as an ID rather than generating one).

If I find a piece with a different ID that is connected I overwrite all pieces with that ID with new ID ( I have an ASSERT here cos it shouldn't actually happen. It hasn't so far in lots of testing)

I don't check_neighbours at the original branch unless the piece has no ID.

This works just fine, though my pseudo is probably missing some small logic.
My problem is that it has the potential to use many branches (which may be a problem on the hardware I am working on). I have worked on the problem so long now that I can't see another solution. Ever get the feeling you are missing something incredibly obvious?

Also I am new to stackoverflow, reasonably new to programming and any advice on etiquette etc is appreciated.

Comment: What limitations are provided by your hardware? Because personally I wouldn't try ID'ing groups together, but instead look at each piece individually and make decisions at 'click' events. Do you have a motivation for checking the 'group state' at each board change?

Comment: Also do diagonals count as a 'row'? And what language are you going to be writing in?

Comment: The intention was to check if there are valid groups left. The hardware allows 32 branches.

Comment: Not diagonals no, sorry.
Oh, I am developing in C++

Comment: How big is your board? And if you are just checking for existence, can you replace each branch as you go through? What I mean is go through spot by spot, check each direction to see if there is a row of three, if there is then you know there is a valid group. Is there a motivation for keeping track of where the branches are?

Comment: It is hard to explain without a full game description. But groups can be of any size >=3 and could, for example, be in an L shape or a T shape. Any configuration where they are 'touching' or 'connected' horizontally and/or vertically will mean they are in the same group. So worst case is 100 connected pieces since the board is 10x10.

I think you are right that I should evaluate the design to avoid having to do it.

Comment: I'm not saying to not do it. This is a computationally inexpensive activity. I'm just saying you don't need to *save* each group, or to store them in any way. If you are just checking to make sure there is a move, then you can stop the process as soon as you find one.

Comment: I don't see any reason to assign IDs to groups and I think that removing group IDs will make code simpler. Try doing that.

Comment: BY saying "branch limitation" do you mean "too many recursive calls"? Because it is possible to get rid of recursion completely.

Comment: That is basically what I am driving at as well. I am trying to understand the motivation for having the ID assignment in the first place, but at first glance I think it can be completely thrown out.

Comment: Ok, so I see the logic for not saving the ID. The only real benefit at this point is that it is then REALLY clear to me if the system is working as I expect. So I have removed that. Thanks for the suggestions.
@SigTerm yes I do mean too many recursive calls. How would you suggest avoiding recursion?
A further question, how does making the function inline affect the number of branches?

Comment: There are number of ways to avoid recursion here: the first thing that pops into my mind is throwing the 4 direction in an array then cycle through that array in a `for` loop. That way you only have to call the function once and you can exit out of it without having to call itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would you suggest avoiding recursion?

As I understand it, your algorithm is basically a "flood fill" with a small twist.

Anyway, to avoid recursion, you need to allocate array to store coordinates of unprocessed items and use queue or fifo. Because you know dimensions of grid (and since it is bejeweled-style(?) game, you should be able to preallocate it pretty much anywhere.

pseudocode for any flood-fill-type recursive algorithm.

```
struct Coord{
    int x, y;
}

typedef std::queue<Coord> CoordQueue;

bool validCoord(Coord coord){
    return (coord.x >= 0) && (coord.y >= 0) 
        && (coord.x < boardSizeX) && (coord.y < boardSizeY);
}

bool mustProcessCoord(Coord coord);

void processAll(){
     CoordQueue coordQueue;
     Coord startPoint = Coord(0, 0);
     coordQueue.pushBack(startPoint);

     while (!coordQueue.empty()){
         const Coord &curCoord = coordQueue.front();
         //do something with current coordinates.
         processCoord(curCoord);

         const int numOffsets = 4;
         const int offsets[numOffsets][2] = {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};
         for (int offsetIndex = 0; offsetIndex < numOffsets; offsetIndex++){
              Coord neighborCoord = Coord(curCoord.x + offsets[offsetIndex][0],
                    curCoord.y + offsets[offsetIndex][1]); 
              if (!isValidCoord(neighborCoord) || !mustProcessCoord(neighborCoord))
                  continue;
              coordQueue.push_back(neighborCoord);
         }

         coordQueue.pop_front();
     }
}
```

See ? no recursion, just a loop. Pretty much any recursive function can be unwrapped into something like that.

If your underlying platform is restrictive and you have no std::queue, use array (ring buffer implemented as array can act like fifo queue) instead. Because you know size of the board, you can precalculate size of array. The rest should be easy.

Comment: Thank you very much, that actually answers several other questions I had also.